# Use models for specific actions on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, models

I'm pretty new on RoR, and I having a hard time to figure out when to use a controller or something else, like a model for specific situations that implies business logic.

Figure that I have a Post model that have a method to share it on Twitter, like this one:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def send_to_twitter!
    Twitter.update("#{self.title} #{self.url}")
  end
end
```

And then, somewhere I have this:

```
Post.find(9).send_to_twitter!
```

I'm not supposed to do this, since I have business logic on a model and theoretically it's not allowed (from what I know). But it's the simplest way to do this kind of tasks.

My question is, is this the right way to do it? **Is there any better way?**
Thanks!

Comment: Where are you calling `Post.find(9).send_to_twitter!` from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Business logic *belongs* in the model. Models store data, and perform actions on that data.  So this is perfectly correct.

Controllers are the glue between your models and your rendered output, as well as processing user input.  Controllers tell models what to do, but the models should be the ones to do it.

The old adage goes "*skinny* controllers, *fat* models". Telling your models what to do should be simple and easy (controller code), even if the code to perform those actions is complex and long (model code).

---

Think of your app like an Airport. The air traffic controller is your "Controller". They tell the plane (the Model) to land when it checks with the other planes (other Models) that its clear and safe. Then it tells the plane to land, but the plane lands itself.

Models should know how to perform tasks with their own data. But deciding *when* to do those tasks is usually what the controller does.

```
class AirPortController
  def request_landing(plane)
    if @landing_planes.size == 0
      plane.land!
      @landing_planes << plane
    else
      plane.request_again_in(5.minutes)
    end
  end
end
```

Controller's tell the models what to do, but the models do it.